# Apache Django "client denied by server configuration" error

Tags: django, apache, http-status-code-403

I found a similar question here, but didn't help me.

I basically have apache setup on my OS X. I also have Django installed.

However, when i try to load the page through the browser locally, i get:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

I have an original httpd.conf with the only modification of enabling vhosts in which I have:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
     DocumentRoot "/Dropbox/project/www/"
     ServerName touch.loc
  #   ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
     ErrorLog "/Dropbox/project/www/log/error.log"
     CustomLog "/Dropbox/project/www/log/access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

And the error.log file gives:

```
[Tue May 03 20:22:56 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /Dropbox/project/www/
```

I read around and it looks like i have to add the following to the httpd.conf:

```
<Directory /Dropbox/project/www >
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

In which case i get:

```
[Tue May 03 20:27:55 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: /Dropbox/project/www/
```

Can someone help me fix this annoyance? How can I further Investigate it?
Does it have to do with users/groups?

UPDATE:
I then added the Options +Indexes and the permissions opened. However when i try to load the page, file structure appears instead of the wsgi file to pickup and load the website. What would be the reason for that?

here is my .wsgi file:

```
 import os
import sys
sys.stdout = sys.stderr
# Add the virtual Python environment site-packages directory to the path
import site
site.addsitedir('/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages')
#If your project is not on your PYTHONPATH by default you can add the following
sys.path.append('/Dropbox/project/www/')
sys.path.append('/Dropbox/project/www/project')

# Avoid ``[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/.python-eggs'`` messages
os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = '/Dropbox/project/www/mod_wsgi/egg-cache'
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'project.settings'



import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be missing anything in your Apache configuration that actually serves the Django application. You need to read the [Django mod_wsgi documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/) - the first line of code there is what you're missing.

Note that your code should not live under the DocumentRoot.

Answer (score 1):

The problem I see is in Dropbox folder
I have made so:

```
chmod o+x /home/your_name/Dropbox
```

That resolves permissions